# Weird JavaScript message in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Getting a weird error for `.stopPropagation()` in `IE`

My code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var options = {
    $this: "",
    $menuItems: $(".mainMenu > li"),
    $blueBar: $(".blueBar"),
    $submenuBg: $("#submenuBg"),
    $sortOptions: $(".sortOptions"),
    $submenu: $(".submenu"),
    submenuClass: ".submenu",
    blueBarClass: ".blueBar",
    selectedClass: "selected",
    sortOptionsClass: ".sortOptions",
    subSubmenu: "ul",
    subSubmenuClass: "sub-submenu"      
    };

    $sortBy.toggle(function(){
            options.$this = $(this);
            ddlShow(event, options);
        }, 
        function(){
            options.$this = $(this);
            ddlHide(options);
        }
    );

});

var ddlShow = function(event, options){
    event.stopPropagation();
    options.$this.children(options.sortOptionsClass).show();    
}

var ddlHide = function(options){
options.$this.children(options.sortOptionsClass).hide();
}
```

Getting the following error:

> object doesn't support property or method 'stoppropagation'

Code works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

How do I solve this?

**Note:** The same code works fine without the `object options`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in IE we do not have stopPropogation method available in javascript on event object. If you will search in google you will find different implementation of event object in ie and webkit based browsers. So in order to correct that jQuery has given a single interface for handling it so you should use jQuery way of doing events to stop getting this errors.

You can read this article to get more clarification http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html

Comment: btw IE9 and further seems to have implemented stopPropagation method - but in my case similar errors occured because the domain that i was trying out was in the list of sites that were running in compatibility mode

Answer (score 6):

replace 
 `e.stopPropagation();`  with 
 `if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation(); else e.cancelBubble = true;` worked for me

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Have your `toggle` handlers accept the event parameter from jQuery:

```
$sortBy.toggle(function(event){ // ADDED PARAMETER
        options.$this = $(this);
        ddlShow(event, options);
    },
```

If you do not do this, then when calling `ddlShow` the argument `event` resolves to `window.event`, which is an object that has not been "normalized" by jQuery for cross-browser consistency.

Comment: @paiCode: [Because FF supports this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.stopPropagation), while IE only does so from version 9 onwards. Similar for Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
$sortBy.toggle(function(){  <-- you must get the event object from jquery.
        options.$this = $(this);
        ddlShow(event, options);
    }, 
    function(){
        options.$this = $(this);
        ddlHide(options);
    }
);
```

Then:

```
$sortBy.toggle(function(event){ ... ddlShow(event, options); }...
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery by default passes the event object, you just have to declare it in the function arguments to use it within the function.

```
$sortBy.toggle(function(event){

    // Do your stuff here

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, It's not advisable to use `event` as argument name.

`event` refers to the global event object. Define something like `e`

```
function(e, options){
    e.stopPropagation();
    //do stuff here    
}
```